# Crystal report - item listing restarts on second page

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to create report in CR where I have a list of items that are shown in a pre-agreed layout and on first page is shown only one item and all the rest is shown on second and farther but after adding a numbering of items I found out that listing starts from the beginning on second page.
for ex: if I have a list of (A,B,C,D,E,F,G) and pre-agreed layout is 1-3-3. . .
so the result should be:
Page-01: A
Page-02: B,C,D
Page-03: E,F,G

but instead I am getting the results in this form :/ :
Page-01: A
Page-02: A,B,C,
Page-03: D,E,F
Page-04: G

please can someone help me ?

in **section expert**, in "new page after" I am using code: **if pagenumber = 1 then remainder (recordnumber,1) = 0 else if pagenumber <> 1 then remainder (recordnumber,3) = 0** 
what am I doing wrong ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how great of a solution this is, but it did work for me. so, if anyone will have the same problem I hope it will work for you as well.

so, to be more detailed about my case, I have details section in my report on first page but no actual field from "details" dataset. just some text box with information.

what I did to solve my problem is that i change the size of first pages detail section (DS).

I have DS-a, DS-b and DS-c. and two different layouts. in first case DS-a is shown only on first page and DS-b afterwards pluse there is no listing on first page, no DS-c at all. for Second layout I have DS-c on first page with listing and DS-b on second and afterwards with continuous listing of items.
which means that, as I showed in example abow, I need to have two type of listing:

> ```
> 1) Page-01:    A       Page-02: B,C,D    Page-03: E,F,G
> 2) Page-01: "blank"    Page-02: A,B,C    Page-03: D,E,F    Page-04: G
> ```

I had no problem with first version but was not able to create second

So, to make listing of "items" begin from number 1 on second page, I set the size of DS-a to its max so it fills the entire part of details on first page and there is no more room for DS-b (though I do set parameters for DS-b to show only from second page). the size for section can be set easily, just enlarge section, insert the vertical line and from properties set lines "position" top = 0 and Bottom = 5700 (line is not necessary to be present, just use it to set the sizes)
it will do the trick, well at least it did for me.
hope this info will be useful for someone

sorry for my English :D